# How to make doas ask for root password

Tags: linux, users, password, root, doas

I want to configure doas so that it asks for root password, but not for normal user password. How do I do that?

Comment: why not use `su` for that? su will ask for root's password

Comment: What thirg said ... `doas` is around so you **don't** have to use the root password, just like linux' `sudo` .. if you have (and want to) use the root password, use `su`.